# Apache Common IO FileItemIterator doesn't return any next value

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-fileupload

I want to use Apache Commons FileUpload to upload multipart data, I am using below code

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
  public UploadData handleUpload(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
    FileItemIterator iterStream = upload.getItemIterator(request);

    while (iterStream.hasNext()) {
      FileItemStream item = iterStream.next();

      InputStream stream = item.openStream();

      if (!item.isFormField()) {
        return this.fileService.uploadFromStream(stream,
          item.getName(),
          item.getContentType(),
          this.principalHolder.getPublicProfile());
      }
    }
    return null;
   }
```

Here, isMultipart return true but FileItemIterator.hasNext() returns nothing, having no files to iterate on.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I had below Bean which overrode the below property in **application.properties** to disable the multipart settings.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false

@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```

Removing this Bean helped me to enable the default configuration to disable the multipart for spring servlet